# Fire event between View Models MVVM + Code Injection (Unity). UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, unity-container, code-injection

I have the next structure. A Container that have two childs. I want that when I click in a child1 element, the child2 refresh the data.

VMLocatos.cs

```
static VMLocator()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();
        container.RegisterType<ContainerVM>();
        container.RegisterType<Child1VM>();
        container.RegisterType<Child2VM>();
    }
    ....
```

ContainerVM.cs

```
    ... Bindind in ContentControl the two user controls Child1V and child2V ..
```

Child1VM
  ... this vm has a list view to pick one.

```
 public Child1VM(IService service)
    {
       ...
       MenuItemClick = new DelegateCommands<ItemClickEventArgs>
       (OnItemClicked,()=>true);
    }
   private void OnItemClicked(ItemClickEventArgs args)
    {
        MenuItem a =(MenuItem) args.ClickedItem ;
        Call To Child2VM.Refresh();    
    }
```

Child2VM.cs

```
   public Child2VM(IService service)
    {
        Elements= servce.GetElements();
    }
   public void refresh()
   {
     ...
   }
```

IService.cs

```
 List<Elemnents> GetElements();
```

I tried to create a property in Iservice like:

```
int Update{ get; set; }
```

and in Service.cs

```
  public int Update
    {
        get
        { return _uptate; }
        set
        {
            _update= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        var Handler = PropertyChanged;
        // Handler is always null
        if (Handler != null)
            Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

and from ChildVM1 update that variable.

```
service.Update = 1;
```

and from ChildVM2 try to suscribe to the property changes.

```
 Update = service.Update;

 public int Update
    {
        get
        {
            No fired when change the variable in service
            return _update;
        }
        set
        {
            No fired when change the variable in service
            update = value;
        }
    }
```

I dont know if a using the best approach because I dont find documentation about injection with unity and fire event from other viewmodel.
Thank for your time

Comment: You can use Prism on top of Unity which has things like EventAggregator that do exactly this. You can also use RX so your VM2 subscribes to the observer in your service and your VM1 causes a call into the service that refreshes the underlying data source and publishes it back onto the observer and VM2 picks it up again. There are may ways to address this problem which are probably nicer than your current approach.

Comment: Thanks very much. With Prism and EventAggregator works fine.